# In web development, what are "term", "taxonomy terms" and "vocabulary"?

Tags: terminology, taxonomy

I need to create 2 more tables with purpose: one table will store tags and categories data (categories can have a hierarchy but tags are not) and another table store relationship between tag, category and content. But I so confused about name of those 2 tables. I'm really a newbie in web development. After googling a bit, I found some words like term, taxonomy terms and vocabulary from drupal and wordpress. But I have no idea what they mean. Can you explain those words and help me give a name for my two tables. Of course if those tables are not well design for my purpose please guide me too.

```
content{
    content_id
    ...
}

table_A{
    type (tag, category, ...)
    name
    parent_id
}

table_B{
    table_A_id
    content_id
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**With relevance to wordpress**, those words are indeed confusing.  If you are using wordpress to build a site, you shouldn't need to worry about the database tables for storing taxonomies and terms as it has built in methods to handle all that.

You'll notice when you're in the wordpress admin panel editing a page or post that there is by default a box on the right which calls itself "Categories" and allows you to create new categories. Once one is created, you can add your posts or pages to any "Categories" you've created. I'm sure you understand that already.

As wordpress releases were built, people started asking for more customizing control over categorizing their content.  So developers added "custom taxonomies" to wordpress. For clarity, I should mention that "Categories" is the name of a default "Taxonomy" built into wordpress.

**A taxonomy is a group of terms.** So when you create a "Category" in the right hand box of the admin panel (say "news" for example), you are creating a "term" named "news" which belongs to the "Categories" taxonomy.

This allows a developer to define their own taxonomy (let's say "products") and associate it with pages, posts or any other "post type". So if it's associated with just plain regular "posts" in the admin panel. A box exactly like the existing "categories" box would show up upoon editing but would call itself "products" instead. Anything added to that list would be a term under the "products" taxonomy.

Hope this clarifies things a bit for using wordpress. These terms can be used differently in different contexts so nothing I've said necessarily applies to anything outside of the wordpress package. Unfortunately there is often no universal "web development" meaning for a given word you may see thrown around in discussion.

Comment: really perfect explanation

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy, last time ago, means categorize life organisms. Similarly, in computer engineering, taxonomy means categorize terms, can be substantive(three, car, cat), verbs(go, be, do). Taxonomy and terms can be mens anything, but the concept is a data structure and hierarchy